# Why does the MsbuildExtension Detokenise class reload the project?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuildcommunitytasks, msbuildextensionpack

This is problematic because any Properties being passed in are lost.

Further Explanation: I pass in a  property to the project file. This property is a path to a .props file. It contains tokens and replacement values for the detokenise class. The task apparently reloads the project and the path is not maintained. This doesn't seem to be the case for other task, for example the guid tasks.

In the example I am using a example proj entitled guids.proj

Invoked Using :

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.Detokenise TaskAction="Detokenise" TargetFiles="@(FileCollectionToBeDetokenized )"/>
```

Some command line out put follows :

`Task "MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.Detokenise" (TaskId:11)
  Detokenise Task Execution Started [13:04:35] (TaskId:11)
  Loading Project: C:\Users\bstrausser\Desktop\guids.proj (TaskId:11)
  Detokenising Collection: 1 files (TaskId:11)
C:\Users\*****\Desktop\guids.proj(37,9): error : Property not found: Asset
Directory`

Full project file :

```
Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="$(ParentMSBuildProjectDirectory)\Bin\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" Condition="Exists('$(ParentMSBuildProjectDirectory)\Bin\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks')"/>
<Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" Condition="!Exists('$(ParentMSBuildProjectDirectory)\Bin\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks') AND Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks')"/>

<PropertyGroup>
    <TPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks</TPath>
    <TPath Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Common\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks')">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Common\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks</TPath>
    <PROPS>$(DACP)</PROPS>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="$(PROPS)" Condition="'$(DACP)' != ''" />

<Target Name="Default">
    <Message text = "$(DACP)" />
    <!-- Create a new Guid and get the formatted and unformatted values -->
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Guid TaskAction="Create">
        <Output TaskParameter="FormattedGuidString" PropertyName="FormattedGuidString1" />
        <Output TaskParameter="GuidString" PropertyName="GuidStringItem" />
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Guid>
    <Message Text="GuidStringItem: $(GuidStringItem)"/>
    <Message Text="FormattedGuidString: $(FormattedGuidString1)"/>
    <!-- Create a new cryptographically strong Guid and get the formatted and unformatted values -->
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Guid TaskAction="CreateCrypto">
        <Output TaskParameter="FormattedGuidString" PropertyName="FormattedGuidString1" />
        <Output TaskParameter="GuidString" PropertyName="GuidStringItem" />
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Guid>
    <Message Text="GuidStringItem Crypto: $(GuidStringItem)"/>
    <Message Text="FormattedGuidString Crypto: $(FormattedGuidString1)"/>

    <ItemGroup>
        <FileCollectionToBeDetokenized Include="C:\Code\MSBuildGit\Configuration\TaskExecutorConfigTransforms\App.GREEN.SCRATCH.config"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Message text = "BaseUrl        : $(BaseUrl)" />
    <Message text = "DetokenizedTransformFile       : @(FileCollectionToBeDetokenized)" />

    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.Detokenise TaskAction="Detokenise" TargetFiles="@(FileCollectionToBeDetokenized )"/>


</Target>
```